# What is the difference between Static method call vs delegate method call?

Tags: c#

Can anyone say the difference between static/object method call vs delegate method call here the sample provided from my end.

```
class Program
{
    private delegate void TestDeleg1(string input1);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Using delege & Lambda expression
        TestDeleg1 testDeleg1 = input => { var test = "Hai " + input; Console.WriteLine(test); };
        testDeleg1("Microsoft");

        // Using simple static method invoke
        TestImplementation("Microsoft");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void TestImplementation(string input1)
    {
        var test = "Hai " + input1;
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}
```

Because I didn't find any real time usage of delegate method call.

Thanks,
S.Venkatesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example.. there's no difference in their usage. Architecturally however, they are quite different. A delegate is a reference to a method. A static method is.. a method.

Delegates can change what method they reference.. however, a method is just that.. a method.

Comment: If you find time share the difference with real usage

Answer (score 1):

The usefulness of delegates also comes from the fact that they are *types* that can be used for example as parameters to methods. For example if you declare

```
internal delegate bool PredicateOnInt32(int x);
```

then `PredicateOnInt32` is a kind of reference type, and you can use it as a parameter in a method, like

```
internal int GetFirstNumberWhere(PredicateOnInt32 pred)
{
  foreach (int num in this.numbers)
  {
    if (pred(num))
      return num;
  }
  throw new InvalidOperationException("No number satisfies the specified prediacte");
}
```

This is just an exemple, of course. But think of LINQ and you understand that it can be useful to have a type that represents a method (or several methods) of a specific signature and return type.

Another use of delegates is in *events* where a delegate instance is used behind the scene to hold the collection of methods to be invoked when the event "happens". For example when a button is clicked. Different "subscribers" can then add their own methods to the delegate, through the add accessor of the event.